svelte page/component caching issue with shared navbar component
I am developing a website currently, and have run into a small problem.
===
Steps to reproduce:
1.npm create svelte@latest test (skeleton, typescript, eslint-prettier-playwright-vitest)
2.cd test
3.npm i
4.npm run dev -- --open (to open in browser for debugging)
5.Create src/components/Navbar.svelte with the following contents:
<script lang="ts">
    import { onMount } from 'svelte';

    function toggleHamburgerMenu() {
        var x = document.getElementById('myLinks') as HTMLDivElement;
        if (x.style.display === 'block') {
            x.style.display = 'none';
        } else {
            x.style.display = 'block';
        }
    }

    function getTranslatedPagePath(): string {
        switch (window.location.pathname) {
            case '/':
                return 'nav.about';
            case '/services':
                return 'nav.services';
            case '/updates':
                return 'nav.updates';
            case '/photos':
                return 'nav.photos';
            case '/contact':
                return 'nav.contact';
            case '/links':
                return 'nav.links';
            default:
                return '';
        }
    }

    $: currentTab = 'nav.about';
    onMount(() => {
        currentTab = getTranslatedPagePath();

        function closeTopnav(this: HTMLAnchorElement) {
            var x = document.getElementById('myLinks') as HTMLDivElement;
            x.style.display = 'none';

            currentTab = this.innerHTML;
        }

        // topnav doesnt close automatically when clicking on a link
        const links = document.getElementsByClassName('topnav_link') as unknown as HTMLAnchorElement[];
        for (let i = 0; i < links.length; ++i) {
            links[i].addEventListener('click', closeTopnav);
        }

        // hide topnav when clicking outside
        document.addEventListener('click', (e: MouseEvent) => {
            var x = document.getElementById('topnav-wrapper') as HTMLDivElement;
            var y: Node = e.target as Node;
            var z = document.getElementById('myLinks') as HTMLDivElement;
            if (!x.contains(y) && z.style.display == 'block') {
                z.style.display = 'none';
            }
        });
    });
</script>

<head>
    <link
        rel="stylesheet"
        href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.5.2/css/all.min.css"
    />
</head>

<div id="topnav-wrapper">
    <div>
        <a href="/"><img src="" alt="Logo" /></a>
    </div>
    <div class="topnav">
        <div id="content">
            <a href="" class="active">{currentTab}</a>
            <a href="" class="icon" on:click={toggleHamburgerMenu}>
                <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div id="myLinks">
            {#each 'about, services, updates, photos, contact, links'.split(', ') as link}
                {#if `nav.${link}` !== currentTab}
                    <a class="topnav_link" href="/{link === 'about' ? '' : link}">{`nav.${link}`}</a>
                {/if}
            {/each}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<style>
    #topnav-wrapper {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;

        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;

        overflow: visible;

        z-index: 100;

        /* background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6); */
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    .topnav {
        overflow: hidden;
        /* background-color: #333; */

        /* width: fit-content; */
        /* height: fit-content; */

        margin: 1.5rem;
    }

    /* Hide the links inside the navigation menu (except for logo/home) */
    .topnav #myLinks {
        display: none;

        position: absolute;
        top: inherit;
        left: inherit;
        background-color: #333;
        pointer-events: all;
    }

    /* Style navigation menu links */
    .topnav a {
        color: white;
        padding: 14px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: block;

        /* width: fit-content; */
        background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.74);
        color: black;
        font-size: 1.5rem;
    }

    /* Style the hamburger menu */
    .topnav a.icon {
        background: black;
        display: block;
    }

    /* Add a grey background color on mouse-over */
    .topnav a:hover {
        background-color: #ddd;
        color: black;
    }

    /* Style the active link (or home/logo) */
    .active {
        background-color: rgb(135, 206, 235);
        color: white;
    }

    img {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
    }

    #content {
        display: flex;
    }

    #logo {
        background-color: white;
        opacity: 70%;
    }

    @media screen and (min-width: 320px) {
        #logo,
        img {
            width: 115px;
            height: 50px;
            margin-left: 15px;
        }
        img {
            top: 20px;
        }
    }

    @media screen and (min-width: 520px) {
        #logo,
        img {
            width: 135px;
            height: 55px;
        }
        img {
            top: 20px;
        }
    }

    @media screen and (min-width: 720px) {
        #logo,
        img {
            width: 155px;
            height: 65px;
            margin-top: 10px;
        }
        img {
            top: 15px;
        }
    }

    @media screen and (min-width: 920px) {
        #logo,
        img {
            width: 175px;
            height: 70px;
        }
        img {
            top: 10px;
        }
    }

    @media screen and (min-width: 1120px) {
        #logo,
        img {
            width: 195px;
            height: 75px;
            margin-top: 20px;
        }
        img {
            top: 10px;
        }
    }

    @media screen and (min-width: 1320px) {
        #logo,
        img {
            width: 215px;
            height: 80px;
        }
        img {
            margin-top: 5px;
        }
    }

    @media screen and (min-width: 1520px) {
        #logo,
        img {
            width: 235px;
            height: 90px;
        }
        img {
            top: 10px;
        }
    }

    @media screen and (min-width: 1720px) {
        #logo,
        img {
            width: 255px;
            height: 100px;
            margin-top: 20px;
        }
        img {
            top: 10px;
        }
    }

    @media screen and (min-width: 1920px) {
        #logo,
        img {
            width: 275px;
            height: 110px;
            margin-top: 20px;
        }
        img {
            top: -10px;
        }
    }

    img {
        top: 0px; /* TODO: responsive */
        margin-top: 0px;
    }

    #content a {
        background-color: transparent;
        color: black;
        font-size: 1.5rem;
    }
</style>

6.Create src/routes/+layout.svelte :
<script>
    import Navbar from '../components/Navbar.svelte';
</script>

<Navbar />
<slot />

7.Create /(about), services, updates, photos, contact, links  routes with a simple h1 to mention the page title to easily understand which route we are in.
8.Go to the browser tab, open the burger menu on the top right, click through every link. Afterwards, if you try to click any of them, the title will not update, the links list will not update deleting the current page link, and the burger menu will not close (but we will go to correct page).
===
The problem I have is that after the first iteration through every link in the navbar, they get cached (or something along those lines I am not quite sure of the underlying mechanisms of svelte) and when I try to click them again:

The navbar currentTab title doesn't update,
The links don't get updates, so I see the link of the currentTab which I shouldn't

The common thing in both those problems is currentTab, I tried to make it a simple var to see if it changes anything but it doesn't so I kinda run out of ideas.
Anybody knows how to fix this?
Expected:

The navbar component to update on each <a> link click, so the title and the list of links update (and the burger menu to close).


Alright, first of all thanks for the very easily reproducible example and instrunctions, it helps a lot. I'll take you through the problems and then leave my own opinion for last.
You're using nchor tags with an empty href attribute in the .content div as a button, that triggers a navigation event in SvelteKit which may be part of the issue. My recommendation would be to simply switch it to simple buttons and style them accordingly.
Regarding the problem of only running in the first iteration there's two issues. First, the closeTopnav() function being declared inside the onMount callback may make it inaccessible after being first called so I moved it to the top level. Second, the callback when attaching event listeners on each link in the onMount seems to be the core issue — as pointed out by brunnerh in the comments, the #if block removes the element once it's clicked and since the onMount only runs once, the event listener attached in the for loop is removed along the element. That's easily fixed by calling the function using the on:click Svelte handler in the link itself, here's your code with the comments where I changed something.
<script lang="ts">
    import { onMount } from 'svelte';

    function toggleHamburgerMenu() {
        var x = document.getElementById('myLinks') as HTMLDivElement;
        if (x.style.display === 'block') {
            x.style.display = 'none';
        } else {
            x.style.display = 'block';
        }
    }

    function closeTopnav(thisTab:string) {
        var x = document.getElementById('myLinks') as HTMLDivElement;
        x.style.display = 'none';

        // I usually avoid .innerHTML and opt for .textContent, but here you can pass the string iself as an argument just like the name of the link itself
        currentTab = thisTab;
    }

    let currentTab:string = 'nav.about';

    onMount(() => {
        //scoped this function to the onMount since this function is only used to find the path when it's mounted
        function getTranslatedPagePath(): string {
            switch (window.location.pathname) {
                case '/':
                    return 'nav.about';
                case '/services':
                    return 'nav.services';
                case '/updates':
                    return 'nav.updates';
                case '/photos':
                    return 'nav.photos';
                case '/contact':
                    return 'nav.contact';
                case '/links':
                    return 'nav.links';
                default:
                    return '';
            }
        }
        currentTab = getTranslatedPagePath();

        // hide topnav when clicking outside
        document.addEventListener('click', (e: MouseEvent) => {
            var x = document.getElementById('topnav-wrapper') as HTMLDivElement;
            var y: Node = e.target as Node;
            var z = document.getElementById('myLinks') as HTMLDivElement;
            if (!x.contains(y) && z.style.display == 'block') {
                z.style.display = 'none';
            }
        });
    });

</script>

<head>
    <link
        rel="stylesheet"
        href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.5.2/css/all.min.css"
    />
</head>

<div id="topnav-wrapper">
    <div>
        <a href="/"><img src="" alt="Logo" /></a>
    </div>
    <div class="topnav">
        <div id="content">
            <div class="active">{currentTab}</div>
            <!-- changed href-less anchors to button -->
            <button class="icon" on:click={toggleHamburgerMenu}>
                <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div id="myLinks">
            {#each 'about, services, updates, photos, contact, links'.split(', ') as link}
                {#if `nav.${link}` !== currentTab}
                    <!-- added click handler in the link itself, passing the concatenated string as argument -->
                    <a class="topnav_link" href="/{link === 'about' ? '' : link}"
                        on:click={() => {closeTopnav(`nav.${link}`)}}
                    >
                        {`nav.${link}`}
                    </a>
                {/if}
            {/each}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<style>
    #topnav-wrapper {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;

        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;

        overflow: visible;

        z-index: 100;

        /* background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6); */
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    .topnav {
        overflow: hidden;
        /* background-color: #333; */

        /* width: fit-content; */
        /* height: fit-content; */

        margin: 1.5rem;
    }

    /* Hide the links inside the navigation menu (except for logo/home) */
    .topnav #myLinks {
        display: none;

        position: absolute;
        top: inherit;
        left: inherit;
        background-color: #333;
        pointer-events: all;
    }

    /* Style navigation menu links */

    /* added button selector */
    .topnav button, .topnav a {
        color: white;
        padding: 14px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: block;
        border: none;
        /* width: fit-content; */
        background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.74);
        color: black;
        font-size: 1.5rem;
    }

    /* Style the hamburger menu */
    /* changed to button selector */
    .topnav button.icon {
        background: black;
        display: block;
    }

    /* Add a grey background color on mouse-over */
    /* changed to button selector */
    .topnav button:hover {
        background-color: #ddd;
        color: black;
    }

    /* Style the active link (or home/logo) */
    .active {
        background-color: rgb(135, 206, 235);
        color: white;
    }

    img {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
    }

    #content {
        display: flex;
    }

    #logo {
        background-color: white;
        opacity: 70%;
    }

    @media screen and (min-width: 320px) {
        #logo,
        img {
            width: 115px;
            height: 50px;
            margin-left: 15px;
        }
        img {
            top: 20px;
        }
    }

    @media screen and (min-width: 520px) {
        #logo,
        img {
            width: 135px;
            height: 55px;
        }
        img {
            top: 20px;
        }
    }

    @media screen and (min-width: 720px) {
        #logo,
        img {
            width: 155px;
            height: 65px;
            margin-top: 10px;
        }
        img {
            top: 15px;
        }
    }

    @media screen and (min-width: 920px) {
        #logo,
        img {
            width: 175px;
            height: 70px;
        }
        img {
            top: 10px;
        }
    }

    @media screen and (min-width: 1120px) {
        #logo,
        img {
            width: 195px;
            height: 75px;
            margin-top: 20px;
        }
        img {
            top: 10px;
        }
    }

    @media screen and (min-width: 1320px) {
        #logo,
        img {
            width: 215px;
            height: 80px;
        }
        img {
            margin-top: 5px;
        }
    }

    @media screen and (min-width: 1520px) {
        #logo,
        img {
            width: 235px;
            height: 90px;
        }
        img {
            top: 10px;
        }
    }

    @media screen and (min-width: 1720px) {
        #logo,
        img {
            width: 255px;
            height: 100px;
            margin-top: 20px;
        }
        img {
            top: 10px;
        }
    }

    @media screen and (min-width: 1920px) {
        #logo,
        img {
            width: 275px;
            height: 110px;
            margin-top: 20px;
        }
        img {
            top: -10px;
        }
    }

    img {
        top: 0px; /* TODO: responsive */
        margin-top: 0px;
    }

    /* changed to button selector */
    #content button {
        background-color: transparent;
        color: black;
        font-size: 1.5rem;
    }
</style>

IMO, you're making use of Vanilla JS in places where Svelte gives you good alternatives, and there's absolutely nothing wrong with it, but life can be better. Some of those were manually attaching the eventListeners with the for loop in the onMount and even the document event listener could be handled by declaring the same function in the top level something like function hideTopnavWhenClickingOutside() {...} and calling in Svelte's document pseudo-element, like such:
<svelte:document on:click={hideTopnavWhenClickingOutside} />

But a big part of the fun in learning Svelte is realizing just how much easier and faster it can make developing, so I hope this helps and that it keeps making your coding journey more and more enjoyable!

(The scope of closeTopnav is not an issue, if it were, TS also would usually yell at you.)

Additional suggestions: Use class: directive to toggle CSS classes based on local state (e.g. let showMenu: boolean) rather than querying the DOM. Even if an element is needed, one should use bind:this instead, that way you cannot accidentally select the wrong element, including those outside the current component. (The core problem here was the combination of attaching events only once while the #if destroys the links along with the event handlers, which are not recreated.)

That's perfect, thanks!

Hey, thanks for taking the time to write a detailed answer! Because I am a beginner in the svelte ecosystem I do realize that sometimes I do not use svelte features that would make my life easier. Thanks for the suggestions, I'll make sure to try them out and come back with the results! Thanks again!

Well I tried it out, and everything works flawlessly! Thank you so much, for taking the time to write out such a detailed and in depth answer! Cheers!
